# If X has Poisson (lambda) distribution then what would be the coverage probability of its confidence interval?

Tags: statistical-inference, poisson-distribution

I was able to calculate the confidence set for lambda here which is dependent on chi-square distribution having df = 2(y0+1) and 2y0 but I am unable to find out its coverage probability

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.